# React getInitialProps not running entire function on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Edit: figured it out - for some reason if I manually copy paste the getReviewOffice/getUsers into my get initial props it works fine *shrug*. I looked into the way I was importing the functions and it looks fine/works for the initialState args.

I'm not very experienced with React. I am having errors while refreshing my page. I think this is my issue: When I am refreshing my page, I think the getInitialProps function is triggering, but for some reason it doesn't appear that it is starting from the beginning. I have an await fetch to get some data, which is being stored in a variable reviewOffice. I am then trying to use reviewOffice.id as an argument for a separate fetch. This is where I'm getting my first error because reviewOffice is considered null. If I try to put a debugger anywhere in the getInitialProps function It is never triggered, in addition If I put any console.log() statements I will not see it, however it will always fail on the second line of the function "let users = await..."

Why doesn't the page await for the first call like I think it should?

```
//index.js
const PagesAdminReviewOffice = ({ initialState }) => {
  initialState = initialize(initialState);

  return (
    <RouteProtect>
      <AdminReviewOfficeMenu>
        <AdministrationStateProvider initialAdministrationState={initialState}>
          <AdminUserConfigProvider>
            <PopWidth>
              <Stack gapSize="32">
                <ReviewOffice></ReviewOffice>
              </Stack>
            </PopWidth>
          </AdminUserConfigProvider>
        </AdministrationStateProvider>
      </AdminReviewOfficeMenu>
    </RouteProtect>
  );
};

PagesAdminReviewOffice.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  let reviewOffice = await getReviewOffice();
  let users = await getUsers(reviewOffice.id);

  let primaryId = await fetchWrapper({
    url: `${HOST}/api/ReviewOffice/Contacts/PrimaryId`,
    req,
  })
  
  var initialState = await getInitialReviewOfficeState(
    getReviewOffice,
    updateReviewOffice,
    getUsers,
    getContacts,
    createAdminUser,
    deleteAdminUser,
    updateContact,
    createContact,
    deleteContact,
    setPrimaryContact,
    getApprovalTypeContacts,
    createApprovalTypeContact,
    updateApprovalTypeContact,
    deleteApprovalTypeContact,
    getApprovalTypes,
    getTags,
    createTag,
    updateTag,
    deleteTag,
    reviewOffice,
    users,
    primaryId
  );

  return {
    initialState: initialState,
  };
};
export default PagesAdminReviewOffice;
```

Here are the functions getReviewOffice() and getUsers(), I forgot to add them in op

```
// reviewOfficeFunctions.js
export const getReviewOffice = (req) => {
  return fetchWrapper({
    url: `${HOST}/api/ReviewOffice`,
    req,
  })
};

export const getUsers = (id, req) => {
  return fetchWrapper({
    url: `${HOST}/api/AdminUser/ReviewOffice/${id}`,
    req,
  });
};
```

And here is my fetchWrapper:

```
const { OAUTH_COOKIE_PREFIX } = get();

const fetchWrapper = async (
  { url, fetchOptions, req },
  returnResponse = false
) => {
  const tokens = grabTokensFromCookies(req, OAUTH_COOKIE_PREFIX);
  let response;
  let json = {};
  try {
    response = await fetchWithTokens({
      ...tokens,
      cookiePrefix: OAUTH_COOKIE_PREFIX,
      url,
      fetchOptions: {
        redirect: "error",
        credentials: "omit",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        ...fetchOptions,
      },
    });

    if (returnResponse) {
      return response;
    }

    const { status } = response;
    if (response.ok) {
      if (response.headers.get("content-length") !== "0") {
        json = response.json();
      }
    } else if ((status === 400 || status === 401) && isBrowser) {
      // 400 Bad Request = invalid refresh token, and various other issues
      // 401 Unauthorized = invalid access token
      // Node tries to refresh the access token, so if we get one of the
      //   above errors it means we need to log in again.
      // Reload allows us to maintain our current page but unfortunately
      //   not state because user will be redirected to the login page.
      //   Consider other ways to respond if this does not meet your needs.
      location.reload();
    } else {
      throw `Response not OK, status: ${status}`;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // 403 Forbidden = not authorized
    // Other errors that can not be handled by attempting to re-authenticate.
    // TODO in your project, handle the error - forward to an error page?
    console.error(err); // eslint-disable-line no-console
    throw err;
  }

  return returnResponse ? response : json;
};

export default fetchWrapper;
```

Comment: are you sure getUsers returns promise?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies in your `fetchWrapper` utility. After looking over the code, the `returnResponse` value is false by default, which means the function attempts to return the JSON data but doesn't appear to wait for the `response.json();` Promise to resolve. Because of this, the initial `json` value of `{}` is returned and `reviewOffice.id` is undefined.

```
const fetchWrapper = async (
  { url, fetchOptions, req },
  returnResponse = false
) => {
  const tokens = grabTokensFromCookies(req, OAUTH_COOKIE_PREFIX);
  let response;
  let json = {};
  try {
    response = await fetchWithTokens({ ..... });

    if (returnResponse) {
      return response;
    }

    const { status } = response;
    if (response.ok) {
      if (response.headers.get("content-length") !== "0") {
        json = await response.json(); // <-- await Promise to resolve
      }
    } else if ((status === 400 || status === 401) && isBrowser) {
      // ...
      location.reload();
    } else {
      throw `Response not OK, status: ${status}`;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    ...
  }

  return returnResponse ? response : json;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, this is my first post so I appreciate feedback

What you're saying makes sense, I added the await response.json() and it didn't appear to fix the issue. When I replaced the two lines in index.js with the functions themselves (i.e. now I have duplicated code) it seemed to clear up the problem, I'm not sure I totally understand the await fix, but would that have anything to do with the problem that might be in FetchWrapper?

Comment: @ClarkKelly Replace the imported functions with their exact duplicate code, or just replace them directly with a call to `fetchWrapper`? (*or is that just the same basically?*) How are these two functions exported/imported for use? Is it possible for you to stand up a *running* Nextjs codesandbox minimal demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?